Excel, Power Query : how to add rows for weeks missing?
I was trying to merge below table with a "week table" in Excel/Power Query.
For all the missing weeks/rows, I get a blank row as expected (right outer join).
However, the issue I ran into, is that the missing/added week is only showing up once.
I would like it to show twice as there 2 styles where eg week13 is missing.
So, is there a way in PQ to add the missing rows/weeks.
(I think I just need the rows to appear. As the style, col, ... info can be added with "Fill->Down" later. Also, the value in the last column will just be 0 for all added rows)
Thanks a lot :)
See image
table

Please edit your question, simplify your data, and provide sample input and sample desired output. Your image is confusing and not helping explain what you want to do

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
